# firefox does not renders font weight correcly unlike chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

My website shows font weight differently in chrome and firefox.

chrome
[image]

firefox
[image]

as you can see, it's hard to distinguish between the bold font and the normal font in firefox. but in chrome it shows just fine. any idea what the problem is and how to make firefox shows the content like chrome?

Comment: Unfortunately this is probably how the browser renders the text. I would try a different font.

Comment: yeah I know but there are some codes that you add it in your html file and make firefox renders it correctly but i couldn't find it.

Comment: try looking at `font-smoothing`

Comment: unfortunately didn't work.